# how to show incremental numbers in php for loop when previous removed in a single textbox without button or clicking

Tags: php, jquery

My problem is that I want to show numbers which  increment in `for_loop` or `while_loop` just only in a single text_box. By increment I **need previous number removed and the new one shows itself based on sleep(1) function preferably**.

once I used `jquery` for removing `div tag` around textbox but in loop only the first one div removed and other showed themselves vertically.

remember I don't want to have button or click for doing this. I need it to be executed automatically.

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have tried, and what is the problem you are facing... At least some code you have. This is not a site to contract someone to do it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use PHP? Using jquery everything is done in the brwoser

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
  $varNumber = $('#myNumber').val();
  $('#myNumber').val(++$varNumber);
}, 5000);
});//]]>  

</script>

<form>
    Numbers: <input type="text" id="myNumber" value="1" />
</form>
```